# Error: This expression has type unit but an expression was expected of type inst list

Tags: ocaml

```
|ScmOp(g,h) ->newList := (createInstList **!newList** a currentReg);
```

This is our code, we received the above error when compiling. The error comes from the **!newList** parameter we send to the recursive function. `newList` is defined as a reference so we sent `!newList` in order to pass its value. When removing the `!` we received an error that we sent a ref for inst list instead of an inst list (eventually we want to send an inst list!).

Comment: (Your code is in a completely unreadable format, sorry. I'm trying to improve it, but it's a lot of work. You should be willing to do this work if you want an answer :-)

Comment: Much better, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I think the problem is that the compiler thinks `createInstList` returns unit. This is due to precedence of `;`, I think.

It looks to me like the `!newlist` at the end is supposed to be the result of the whole `createInstList` function. But I suspect that it's being treated as part of the inner `match`.

You might try this:

```
let rec createInstList instList expr currentReg =
    let newList = ref instList in
    (match
           ...
        done);
    !newList
```

Comment: Hey, first of all, thanks for your quick response! unfortonatly it didn't resolve the issue, it caused another error of not recognizing the ScmOp and other types defined in the start. the done; is there in order to finish the loop. you are right, the !newList should be the result of the whole createInstList, but unfortonatly its not recognize it. any other suggestion?

Comment: It's hard to help without having enough code to compile myself. But this seems like there is a lot of support code. If it caused another error, this could be an improvement. There could easily be more than one problem.

Comment: I don't think it's an improvment since it recognized these types before. this is the error:                                                                                  Warning 8: this pattern-matching is not exhaustive.
Here is an example of a value that is not matched:
ScmOp (_, [])                                                                                                         I think you are right and it doesn't recognize that the !newList is the result of the whole recursive call but the solution you suggested did not resolve it, unfortonatly.

Comment: This looks like an improvement to me :-) I suspect your matches actually are non-exhaustive. It's not about recognizing the types, it's about covering all the cases. I can't tell for sure without seeing the type definitions. But you can figure it out.

Comment: Thanks!!! You were more then right... We really had a missing case. thanks again :)